# CSS Using :after and :last-child together

Tags: css

I am trying to combine the pseudo elements :**after** and **:last-child** together but do not seem to be having any luck.

I have a list of radios with labels that are 1-10. Because of the last label being 10 and a double integer the positions are wrong. Thus I am trying to access that last one only.

This fiddle might make it clear what I mean:

## JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/L2n4m3w3/

as you can see, the last one is slightly off center

Here is how I am trying to get the last element:

```
input[name='happy-score']:last-child + label:after {
    left: 0px;
}
```

However this has no effect what so ever.

I also tried:

```
input[name='happy-score']+ label:last-child:after {
    left: 0px;
}
```

However, this seems to affect all the elements, see this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0acLrna0/

Comment: just try like this`input[name='happy-score'], input[name='happy-score'] label:last-child:after {
    left: 0px;
}`

Comment: If you want to find the last label just do ***li:last-child label {***

Comment: Is it always exactly 10...because if it is why not just use #radio-10 that is already in your markup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use this css for the label of last child:
`li:last-child input[name='happy-score'] + label:after {
   left: 0px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use this and check once

```
ul.horizontal-list li:last-child label::before {
    left: 0px;
}
ul.horizontal-list li:last-child label::after {
    left: -10px;
}
```